# Model-driven Power App using SharePoint site for document upload - hide commands for Document Location

Tags: sharepoint, dynamics-crm, powerapps, powerapps-modeldriven, model-driven-app

In my model-driven Power App I set a SharePoint site in the environment's Admin Center Document Management Settings and via these settings create a folder for my entity. When I create a new instance of the entity I have the options to create a document or upload a document file which goes to a subfolder for this instance in the main entity folder.

I see commands (buttons) 'Document Location', 'Open Location', 'Add Location', 'Edit Location' (amongst others).
How can I remove/hide these commands? Hiding them through the [Ribbon Workbench](https://www.develop1.net/public/rwb/ribbonworkbench.aspx) tool doesn't work (I tried hiding the Location-related commands of table Document Location in that tool but they were not shown, just standard commands such as 'Assign', 'Edit', etc. were shown).

Editing the security roles for table Document Location via the Admin Center is not good enough, the users need 'Add Location' privileges ('Create', 'Append to', etc.) in order to upload in the first place (I believe these privileges allow the creation of subfolder per entity). However, if the users start adding non-default locations through 'Add location' command, tracking the documents and the user experience gets messy.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You definetly can hide it using Ribbon Workbench

> I tried hiding the Location-related commands of table **Document Location** in that tool but they were not shown, just standard commands such as 'Assign', 'Edit', etc. were shown

You were looking at the wrong table. The table should be **SharePoint Document**, schema name: *SharePointDocument*, then look at the SubGrid buttons (2nd row)

Once you load the table you should be able to hide all the buttons except the Show Related Records button, which will just open the same subgrid in a new tab.